# Go json Unmarshaller is not called

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm fairly new to Golang. And I was looking for a way to do some custom stuff for marshaling and unmarshalling `json`. I have found the solution to implement `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` interfaces.

Here is my `struct` with implemented interfaces (I have also implemented Stringer):

```
type Data struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
    bar string
}

func (d Data) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte("{\"foo\":\"test\",\"bar\":\"data\"}"), nil
}

func (d Data) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Foo: %s, bar: %s", d.Foo, d.bar)
}

func (d Data) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    d.bar = "testtest"
    d.Foo = "data"
    return nil
}
```

For `Marshaller` everything works as expected:

```
data := &Data{}
marshal, _ := json.Marshal(data)
fmt.Println(string(marshal))
```

The output as expected:

> {"foo":"test","bar":"data"}

But Unmarshaller doesn't work as I was expecting:

```
jsonData := "{\"foo\":\"test\"}"
data := Data{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), data)
fmt.Println(data)
```

This code prints:

> Foo: , bar:

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few distinct problems here.

- The method receiver must be a pointer if you want to modify the receiver, otherwise you're only modifying the copy local to the method.
- You always need to unmarshal into a pointer.
- You're declaring a `"field"` json tag for the `Foo` field, but passing in `"foo"`
- You're calling `json.Unmarshal` inside your `UnmarshalJSON` method, which is going to recurse indefinitely.

A working example would look like

```
func (d *Data) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type data Data
    tmp := &data{bar: "bar"}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *d = Data(*tmp)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonData := "{\"field\":\"test\"}"
    data := Data{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &data)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", data)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FnF2li63dt

Comment: Sorry, the points number 3 and 4 is my fault. I have made the changes inside my editor but didn't copy it to here.

Comment: With the pointer it works, thank you. But I found a little bit strange that you have to implement a method on a pointer to make this work. It's not so obvious to me, maybe it's just because I'm new to Golang

Answer (score 0):

`Data` methods has value receiver, but the variable data has pointer type (`*Data`).

Pointer type variables cannot use functions with value receiver. Either change variable type or receiver type.

Also see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type about receivers.