# Unmarshaling JSON with custom UnmarshalJSON in member slice type fails

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a type

```
type  Block struct {
    //some string and int types, unmarshaling ok
    Transactions []Tx //this fails
}


type Tx struct {
    Sender []byte
    Recipient []byte
    Timestamp time.Time
}

 func (t Tx) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
   var f interface{}
   err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

   m := f.(map[string]interface{})
   for k, v := range m { 
    if k == "Sender" {
      t.Sender, _ = hex.DecodeString(v.(string))
    }   
    if k == "Recipient" {
      t.Recipient, _ = hex.DecodeString(v.(string))
    }   
    if k == "Timestamp" {
      t.Timestamp, _ = time.Parse(time.UnixDate, v.(string))
    }   
  }
  return nil
 }
```

When marshaling a `Block` and then unmarshaling, all the `Block`'s members seem to be correctly marshaled. But for all `Tx` instances, I get an empty value (so if the marshaling object had 3 Tx, the unmarshaled has also 3, but they are empty value).
If I print `t` in the `UnmarshalJSON` function, it actually seems to convert correctly though. Somehow it just does not "finish" the conversion, or the data gets lost, or I don't know what's going on....

What am I missing?

Comment: The changes to `t` in UnmarshalJSON are discarded because the method has a value receiver. Change the code to: `func (t *Tx) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error { ... }`.  Also, please post an [mcve] (include example JSON and surrounding code.

Comment: See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618940/how-can-i-implement-unmarshaljson-for-a-type-derived-from-a-scalar-in-go),  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448102/go-json-unmarshaller-is-not-called).

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks, the pointer as value receiver fixes it! I swear I tried, but there must have been some other issue before which was breaking things. If you care, you can provide that as an answer so that I can accept it.